# No digital audio option on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

Using Asus P7P55E-Pro motherboard that have VT1828S. The card is onboard. I have analog outputs and also extra SPDIF Coaxial and Optical out.

`aplay -l | grep card`

```
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 0: VT1828S Analog [VT1828S Analog]
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 2: VT1828S Alt Analog [VT1828S Alt Analog]
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 3: VT1828S Digital [VT1828S Digital]
```

In system setting sound i only have built in audio analog and no Built-in Digital out
The audio control https://ibb.co/MZjdV8p/

I would like to have it to connect to AV Receiver. It's working on windows side.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution worked for me:

[IEC958 (S/PDIF) not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1098666/iec958-s-pdif-not-working)

sudo apt install libavresample-dev pavucontrol libasound2-plugins-extra